# iOS: Call JS function with 2 parameters in a Webview using SwiftUI

Tags: javascript, swift, webview

I am trying to call my JS function in my webview that takes 2 parameters using the evaluateJS however I do no appear to be hitting the function. (It works without params so I think I am getting the syntax wrong on the SwiftUI side. Wondering if anyone can advise please.

JS function:

```
function testFunction(message, ident) {
    document.getElementById('index_registernow').style.display = 'none';
}
```

SwiftUI side:

```
let token = (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Token") ?? "")
let ident = (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Ident") ?? "")

uiView.evaluateJavaScript("testFunction(\(token),\(ident))")
```

Comment: This is just Swift, not SwiftUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming everything else is working (like there being values for `Token` and `Ident` and your Javascript function existing), the main issue looks like you're not wrapping your strings in quotes in Javascript:

```
uiView.evaluateJavaScript("testFunction(\"\(token)\",\"\(ident)\")")
```